# Set jsp variable to value of a links id

Tags: mysql, jsp

I'm building a simple forum where the SQL query changes whats pulled out by what link is clicked and what I thought I could do was just set a varaible to the value of the topic name and it would give each row their own variable value, but it overwrites it everytime it loops through the forEach and only ever pulls out data for the last row it outputs, but with the id of the `<a>` it sets the value to the right row in the table.

Is there anyway I can set the variable to the value of the `<a>` id or would I have to populate an array full and set the varaible to the value of the next element of the array

```
<td><a id="${row.topic_name}" href="ViewPosts.jsp" onclick='<c:set var="post" value="" scope="application"></c:set>'><c:out value="${row.topic_name}"></c:out></a></td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit of a roundabout solution didn't take too much code though, used javascript to get the id passed it to a hidden input and got the javascript to auto submit to a jsp file that forwarded the parameter I needed onto the jsp page that called the query.